# Flip Table Row Content On Toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I want flip table row content when toggle. Current CSS code:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    table-layout: fixed;
    color: black;
}

td {
    background-color: #FFD65E;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    padding: 10px;
}

td:hover {
    background-color: #febf04;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YAPPF/

I want horizontal flip animation. So, there will have 2 content, first on front and second is when hovered (back). How can I do this?

Comment: Flip in the sense you want that particular box to be rotated when it is hovered ??

Comment: @Yiedpozi - what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is taken from the blog of David Walsh i hope it can you help you
Check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GaganGami/36XDZ/)**

```
<div class="flip-container">
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front">
                front
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                back
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this having only one graphic for an "arrow", but flipping it around to point in different directions.

---

```
img {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

---

If you find difficulty understanding this than please go to this link
http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip